# Можно ли временно остановить onLocationChanged?

Tags: android, gps

День добрый! У меня сейчас приложение постоянно с помощью `onLocationChanged` посылает данные на сервер. Подскажите, во время посыла `Lat Lon` на сервер можно ли временно остановить `onLocationChanged`? Или может у Вас есть другие идеи по реализации и решению данной проблемы.

Comment: пока посылаете кэшируйте координаты из обработчика, как закончите посылать, посылайте теперь последние полученные. А вообще лучше настроить интервал отправки на сервер и слать в соответствии с ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что пришло в голову:
Заведите локальную `int` переменную,
при каждом вызове `onLocationChanged` наращивайте и когда она достигает определённой величины, посылаете запрос и обнуляете переменную) типо

```
a++;
if (a == 1000){
  запрос;
  а = 0;
}
```

ещё как вариант, в отдельном потоке написать таймер, который скажем каждую минуту устанавливает флаг в true, при вызове `onLocationChanged` проверять флаг и если он true, выполнять запрос после чего флаг переводить в false. Тогда запросы будут отправляться минимум раз в минуту, максимум - зависит от частоты опроса.

Comment: это не гарантирует, что одновременно будет послан только один запрос для малой границы. Для больших значений управлять интервалом получения координат будет неудобно. При опросе раз в секунду, вы получите информацию о координатах на сервере раз в 16 минут. А при опросе раз в минуту, соответственно раз в 16 часов. Ну и смысл в таком подходе? Явно нельзя связывать количество опросов с количеством отправок на сервер.

Comment: Воспользовался ASync и IF проверкой пока не получил определенный параметр. Т.к нет вариантов других, выберу лучшим этот!)